# wp_logout Not Logging Me Out

Tags: logout

Here is what I'm doing:

```
wp_logout();
var_dump(is_user_logged_in());
```

var_dump returns:

```
bool(true)
```

Why is wp_logout() not logging me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**wp_logout()** calls [clear_auth_cookie()](http://lab.yukei.net/wp-code/wp-includes/pluggable.php.source.html#l709;), which expires all authorization cookies set. It doesn't change the value of the global **$current_user** variable. So technically you're still logged in for the duration of the script.

If you're using `wp_logout` in your own code, its probably best to `exit` or `wp_redirect` immediately afterwards.

You can call `wp_set_current_user(0)` after `wp_logout()` to manually log the user out instantly, if you need to continue executing PHP but don't want the user to be logged in

Comment: None of this seems to work. After wp_logout() I have tried unset($current_user) and wp_redirect(get_bloginfo("url"));

Comment: You can call `wp_set_current_user(0);` after `wp_logout()` to manually log the user out instantly, if you need to continue executing PHP but don't want the user to be logged in...

Comment: Couldn't get wp_redirect() to work so instead I'm using: `wp_logout(); auth_redirect();` which worked perfectly for me

Comment: First wp_logout(); then wp_set_current_user(0); .. Work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my code. I was trying to logout by using wp_logout() but It wasn't working perfectly as per my need because of some code changes so I used wp_destroy_current_session(); and then wp_redirect(); and exit();

```
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect(site_url()); 
    exit();
```

And it woked for me. 
 you can also use 
        auth_redirect();
instead of  wp_redirect(site_url()); and also in my case wp_set_current_user(0); was also not working if used before redirect as it was setting user 0 active